# An inequality involving fractional Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, fractional-calculus

I have to prove that for $s\in(0,1)$, $u\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, (i.e. $u$ is a Schwartz function):
$$ |(-\Delta)^su(x)|\leq c_{n,s}|x|^{-n-2s},\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1(0), $$
for some $c_{n,s}>0$, where
$$(-\Delta)^su(x):=-\frac{C(n,s)}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{u(x+y)+u(x-y)-2u(x)}
{|y|^{n+2s}}\,dy,\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n, $$
is the fractional Laplacian. I have no idea. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The constant $c_{n, s}$ should depend on $u$. Or $u$ should be not arbitrary Schwartz function.

Comment: And if $c_{n,s}$ is allowed to depend on $u$, then simply split the integral into two parts. The integral over $B(x, 1)$ is bounded by the sup norm of second derivatives of $u$ over $B(x, 1)$ times a constant (by Taylor's theorem). The integral over the complement of $B(x, 1)$ is bounded by a constant times the convolution of $(1 + |x|)^{-n - 2s}$ with itself, which is again bounded by a constant times $(1 + |x|)^{-n - 2s}$.

Comment: @Mateusz Kwaśnicki .Can you give me the details please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$\begin{aligned} -(-\Delta)^s u(x) & = \frac{C(n,s)}{2} \int_{B(x,1)} \frac{u(x + y) + u(x - y) - 2 u(x)}{|y|^{n + 2s}} \, dy \\ & \qquad + C(n,s) \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(0,1)} \frac{u(x - y) - u(x)}{|y|^{n + 2s}} \, dy . \end{aligned}$$
Using Taylor's theorem and the fact that $u''$ is Schwartz class, we find that
$$|u(x + y) + u(x - y) - 2 u(x)| \leqslant C_n |y|^2 \sup_{B(x, 1)} |u''| \leqslant C_{u,n} (1 + |x|)^{-n - 2s} |y|^2 $$
(here and below $C_p$ denotes some constant that only depends on the parameter $p$; the value of $C_p$ can be different each time it appears). Thus,
$$\begin{aligned} \biggl| \int_{B(0,1)} \frac{u(x + y) + u(x - y) - 2 u(x)}{|y|^{n + 2s}} \, dy \biggr| & \leqslant \frac{C_{u,n}}{(1 + |x|)^{n + 2s}} \int_{B(0,1)} |y|^{2-n-2s} dy \\ & = \frac{C_{u,n,s}}{(1 + |x|)^{n+2s}} \end{aligned}$$
Furthermore, since $u$ is Schwartz class, we have
$$|u(x + y) - u(x)| \leqslant |u(x - y)| + |u(x)| \leqslant C_u ((1 + |x - y|)^{-n-2s} + (1 + |x|)^{-n-2s}).$$
It is a nice exercise to show that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(0,1)} \frac{1}{|y|^{n + 2s} (1 + |x - y|)^{n + 2 s}} \, dy \leqslant \frac{C_{n,s}}{(1 + |x|)^{n + 2s}} \, . $$
It follows that
$$\begin{aligned} \biggl| \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(0,1)} \frac{u(x - y) - u(x)}{|y|^{n + 2s}} \, dy \biggr| & \leqslant C_u \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(0,1)} \frac{1}{|y|^{n + 2s} (1 + |x - y|)^{n + 2 s}} \, dy \\ & \qquad + \frac{C_u}{(1 + |x|)^{n + 2 s}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(0,1)} \frac{1}{|y|^{n + 2s}} \, dy \\ & \leqslant \frac{C_{u,n,s}}{(1 + |x|)^{n + 2 s}} + \frac{C_{u,n,s}}{(1 + |x|)^{n + 2 s}} = \frac{C_{u,n,s}}{(1 + |x|)^{n + 2 s}} \, .\end{aligned} $$
The desired result follows:
$$ |(-\Delta)^s u(x)| \leqslant \frac{C_{u,n,s}}{(1 + |x|)^{n + 2 s}} \, .$$

Comment: in equation (1) i don't understand because $C_n|y|^2\sup |D^2u|\leq C_{u,n}(1+|x|)^{-n-2s}|y|^2$.

Comment: @inoc: All second-order derivatives are Schwartz class, and hence $|D^2 u(x)| \leqslant C_u (2 + |x|)^{-n-2s}$. Furthermore, $\sup_{z \in B(x,1)} (2 + |z|)^{-n-2s} \leqslant (2 + (|x| - 1))^{-n-2s} = (1 + |x|)^{-n-2s}$.

Comment: Can you give a me suggestion for prove that: $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1(0}\frac{1}{|y|^{n+2s}(1+|x-y|)^{n+2s}}\,dy\leq\frac{C_{n,s}}{(1+|x|)^{n+2s}},$$ please.

Comment: @inoc: Split the integral into two half-spaces: $\{y : x \cdot y \le \tfrac{1}{2} |x|^2\}$ and the other one. In each integral, estimate one term under the integral by the supremum (which is $(1+|x|/2)^{-n-2s}$), and the other one has finite integral even over all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I noted that: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1(0)}\frac{(1+|x|)^{n+2s}}{|y|^{n+2s}(1+|x|)^{n+2s}}\,dy\leq  C_{n,s},$$ since the function: $$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\frac{1+|x|}{1+|x+y|}\in(0,\infty),$$ is bounded. By this follow: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_1(0)}\frac{1}{|y|^{n+2s}(1+|x+y|)^{n+2s}}\,dy\leq\frac{C_{n,s}}{(1+|x|)^{n+2s}}.$$ Is correct this argument ?

Comment: The function $(1+|x|)/(1+|x+y|)$ seems to be unbounded when, for example, $y = -x$, $|x| \to \infty$.

Comment: Can you give more details for estimate the integral into two half-space $\{y:x\cdot y\leq |x|^2/2\}$, please?

Comment: When $|x|>1$, substitute $y=(x+z)/2$ to get $C\int_{B(x,1)^c}|x+z|^{-n-2s}(1+|x-z|)^{-n-2s}dz$. In $H_+=\{z:\langle z,x\rangle>0\}$ we have $|x+z|\geqslant|x|$, and hence $\int_{H_+}(\cdots)dz\leqslant|x|^{-n-2s}\int(1+|x-z|)^{-n-2s}dz\leqslant C|x|^{-n-2s}$. Similarly, in $H_-=\{z:\langle z,x\rangle<0\}\setminus B(x,1)$, we have $|x-z|\geqslant|x|$, so that $\int_{H_-}(\cdots)dz\leqslant(1+|x|)^{-n-2s}\int_{B(x,1)^c}(1+|x-z|)^{-n-2s}dz\leqslant C|x|^{-n-2s}$. It follows that $\int(\cdots)dz\leqslant C|x|^{-n-2s}$. When $|x|<1$, a trivial bound by $\int(1+|x-y|)^{-n-2s}dy\leqslant C$ applies.